# Magento install error -> In Installer.php line 545: Missing following extensions: 'intl'

Tags: php, error, magento2.4

How to fix this error that I get when installing Magento?

In Installer.php line 545:
Missing following extensions: 'intl'

Php Version 7.4.20
Magento 2.4.1

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you need to so is just enable the extension for that

```
open your php.ini file
find for ;extension=php_intl.dll
remove the comment ;
```

I Hope help this

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: I♥U Thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You php intl Extension is Missing

if you are using ubuntu just try

```
apt-get intall php7.X-intl
```

where `x` is current php version like `2`, `3`, `4`